# Ajax in browser's console

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, console

Is it possible to execute / create ajax calls by manually typing the code to the console of a browser? How is it done if it is the case? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Yes, just execute your code in the console, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this exactly the same way as you do it in a script of your html document.

Just paste the `$.ajax();`-Call in the console, if you use jQuery.